# http handler asp.net

Tags: asp.net

High I'm trying to get a http handler working in iis 7.5 on my local machine. In the  mode on visual studio iis my handler works with the web config set to.

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="GET" path="ShowImages.ashx" type="achangeoftack_new_web.ShowImages" />
</httpHandlers>
```

but when deployed it throws errors so I've set it to

```
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
<handlers>
  <add name="ShowImages.ashx" verb="GET" path="~/ShowImages.ashx" type="achangeoftack_new_web.ShowImages" />
</handlers>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="true" />
```

But I'm still getting no luck with the handler working. I think I've tried everything now I'm starting to pull my hair out.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an ASHX, you don't need to do the registration in your web.config, just use it like a page url e.g.

```
<img src="ShowImages.ashx?id=SomeImageId" />
```

and it'll just work. So I'd try taking those elements out of your web.config and see if that fixes your errors.

**Why This Works**
When you run `aspnet_regiis` on a machine, ASHX is one of the extensions that's registered into IIS for you.
[image]

At runtime when IIS receives a request for an ASHX file, it passes it across to ASP.NET and ASP.NET then resolves it in the same way as for a page or user control, and your code gets run.

You only need to register your handler in web.config if you've written a handler in a standalone class.